# Differential equation notation about maximal solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I'm doing the following problem:
The differential equation 
$$ \dot{y} = X(t,y), X(t,y) =  \frac{1}{3}y^{1/4} +t^{1/3}$$
defined on $D_X = (0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$.

I already solved it with: $y(t) = t^{4/3}$.

**But here is what i don't understand**. The problem says:

For $\eta >0$ let $(I_\eta,y_\eta)$ denote the maximal solution with $y_\eta(1) = \eta$

for:

a) For $0 < \eta < 1 $ Then $y_\eta(t) < t^{4/3}$, for $t \in I_\eta$

b) For $\eta > 1 $ Then $y_\eta(t) > t^{4/3}$, for $t \in I_\eta$

I am very confused about the  $y_\eta(1) = \eta$
 notation, so i can't understand what the goal with the task is. Can you help?

Comment: $y_\eta$ denotes the maximal solution of the equation satisfying the initial condition $y(1)=\eta$. $I_\eta$ stands for the domain of that maximal solution. You have obtained a solution of the equation for $\eta=1$ only.

Comment: I see. Thank you